# message notification error catch admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I try to show in notification the error of the catch like this:

```
  .catch(e => {
    console.error('catch', e);
    showNotification(e, 'warning');
  });
```

This doesn't work.

I follow the instructions on [Actions admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Actions.md)

In this are examples like:

```
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
            showNotification('Error: comment not approved', 'warning')
        });
```

but I want to show in showNotification the `e` message.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i already resolved it.

```
   .catch(e => {
        console.error('Error en handleUploadFile: ', e);
        showNotification(`Error: ${e.message}`, 'warning');
      });
```

Comment: Then please mark your own answer as solving the question.